# UIView disappear on smaller screen

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

I do not have a lot of experience with constraints. Usually the one generated automatically by xCode are fine. I am trying to create a tableViewCell with a lable on the left and a view on the right. On iPad this works fine, however on iphone 4s the view disappear from the cell. Can you pleas help me?
[Used constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5P3t.png)

Comment: You'll need to actually show the constraints you've created, they can't be seen from that image.

Comment: Maybe you have fixed width for label, it's hard to say from your screen. Give us more